# C++: calling constructor with initialization list

Tags: c++

It's possible to initialize c++ vector as below:

```
vector<int> a(5,0);
vector<int> a{0,0,0,0,0};
```

But if one write

```
vector<int> a{5,0};
```

A vector with 2 elements instead of 5 elements is created, i.e. the constructor of vector taking initializer list as argument is called.
But such grammar is also possible:

```
struct myData {
  int k,v;
}
myData mydata{myk, myv};
```

So my question is, when I write `vector<int> a{5,0}`, why the constructor `vector(initializer_list L)` is called, instead of `vector(int k, int v)`?

My guess is, if a constructor consuming initializer list exists, it will be called, otherwise the initializer list is regarded as argument list. But I'm not sure about this.

Comment: [Your guess is correct](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization#Explanation). But the example with the structure isn't really revelant, because it's an aggregate initialization, not a constructor call.

Comment: Useful watching: [The Nightmare of Initialization in C++](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DTlWPgX6zs)